# accessing array with object

Tags: android-emulator

hi i have two classes in android and in one class i have write an array and i want to access it in the main class but the error is give me that "force closed" here is my code

```
package com.semanticnotion.DAO;


import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class DAO extends Activity 
{
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        WordsDAO DAO = new WordsDAO(new String[] "Arte","Arquitectura","Familia","Moda","Cotilleos","Cine","Libros","Historia","Pintura","Musica","Tendencies","Modernimso","Pop art","Masteialismo","realities","filosofia","moda","fotografia","religion"});


        Button next = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button01);
        next.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), WordsDAO.class);
                startActivity(myIntent);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

and the second class code is

```
package com.semanticnotion.DAO;

public class WordsDAO  
{
    String[] words = new String[] "Arte","Arquitectura","Familia","Moda","Cotilleos","Cine","Libros","Historia","Pintura","Musica","Tendencies","Modernimso","Pop art","Masteialismo","realities","filosofia","moda","fotografia","religion"};


    public  WordsDAO(String[] words ) 
    {
        this.words=words;
    }
}
```

please any one tell what well be the error in this code thaks

Answer (score 0):

First of all: the constructor in your second class would not be used. The way to pass parameters to another activity is to use `Intent.putExtra` in the code calling the other activity and in your other activity use

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras(); 
if(extras !=null)
{
    String value = extras.getString("keyName");
}
```

to get the data in `onCreate`.

That said, I guess the problem arises from your second class not providing an explicit parameterless constructor.