# accessing array with object

Tags: android

hi i have two classes in android and in one class i have write an array and i want to access it in the main class but the error is give me that "force closed" here is my code

```
package com.semanticnotion.DAO;


import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class DAO extends Activity {

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

WordsDAO DAO = new WordsDAO(new String[]{"Arte","Arquitectura","Familia","Moda","Cotilleos","Cine","Libros","Historia","Pintura","Musica","Tendencies","Modernimso","Pop art","Masteialismo","realities","filosofia","moda","fotografia","religion"});


Button next = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button01);
next.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View view) {
        Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), WordsDAO.class);

        startActivity(myIntent);
        }
    });
    }
}
```

and the second class code is

```
package com.semanticnotion.DAO;

public class WordsDAO  {


 String[] words = new String[]{"Arte","Arquitectura","Familia","Moda","Cotilleos","Cine","Libros","Historia","Pintura","Musica","Tendencies","Modernimso","Pop art","Masteialismo","realities","filosofia","moda","fotografia","religion"};




 public  WordsDAO(String[] words ) {
  this.words=words;
   }
```

please any one tell what well be the error in this code thaks

Comment: Is this an exact duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3987349/accessing-array-with-object? Don't do that.

Answer (score 1):

The error is probably here:

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), WordsDAO.class);
```

(You should post the error trace)

The Intent constructor expects a Component (Activity) class as the second argument. An arbitrary class isn't allowed.

The easiest way to do what you want is to use [putExtra](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#putExtra%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.CharSequence%5b%5d%29). You can pass a CharSequence array with this method and then retrieve it with getCharSequenceArrayExtra.